# Generating dynamic CSS

Tags: css, django, dynamically-generated

What is the best way to handle style that that is user-customized? Just as an example of the result I'm looking for, this would suffice:

```
body {
   color: {{ user.profile.text_color }};
}
```

However, serving CSS as a view seems like it would cause a significant amount of overhead in a file that is constantly requested, so this is probably not a good solution.

The user does not have access to the CSS files and we must assume that they have no web development knowledge.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> However, serving CSS as a view seems like it would cause a significant amount of overhead in a file that is constantly requested, so this is probably not a good solution.

And what if you would generate that CSS once?

1. Default CSS is: `/common/css.css`
2. Member customize CSS, now `<link />` elements points to `/user-specific/123.css?ts=123123123`. `123` is of course an identifier of the member, and `ts` parameter contains a timestamp - a date of last CSS modification
3. Make sure that your CSS generator sets proper HTTP headers responsible for client-side caching
4. User browser request a CSS file - server replies with simple `304 Not Modified` header - there is no need for any script execution or contents download
5. When member modifies his CSS then you just update `ts` - once again just a single request is needed

Answer (score 5):

Do the CSS dynamically via a view as normal, but use aggressive [caching](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) so that it loads quickly.

Comment: This solution is a bit simplistic. The CSS is on a *per user* basis and to cache properly that means a different cache item for each possible setting. An alternative is to cache 98% of the page, but use a dynamic outer-wrapper `<div class="{{style_choice}}"> ... whatever ... </div>` that uses the per-user setting. Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to tweak the outer class, but that may not be acceptable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try django mediagenerato, actually I read this Q and I was searching for solution like you, then I found that [Django-mediagenerator](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/08/django-mediagenerator-total-asset-management)

I didn't tried it yet but it seams to be a solution.