# Django staticfiles images not showing

Tags: html, css, django, image, django-templates

I worked out how to link my CSS files to my HTML with Django but I can't figure out how to get my images to show in my base.html file.

These are my files, and this is how I added images, maybe I'm doing something wrong?
[pic with all the files and directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHB0A.png)
first, I made a static directory and then I made two sub-directories, CSS and Images. I put my css files in the css directory and then I put my images where my images directory is. 
Then I used this piece of code to try to add uptown.jpg as my background in css.

```
 header {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 
 0.5)), 
   url({% static 'static/images/uptown.jpg' %});
   height: 65vh;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
  }
```

But the image never appeared, on my website. I also tried to link it just how I would normally do it in a css file without Django tags but still didn't work.

I have everything set up in my settings.py in terms of the staticfiles_dir and all. so I'm not sure what the problem is, so please help.

here's my urls and settings.py:

```
    """ask_uptown_personal_project URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r"^test/$", views.TestPage.as_view(), name="test"),
    url(r"^thanks/$", views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name="thanks"),
    url(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^accounts/", include("accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")),
    url(r"^accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    url(r"^posts/", include("posts.urls", namespace="posts")),
    url(r"^groups/",include("groups.urls", namespace="groups")),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    enter code here
```

settings:

```
"""
Django settings for ask_uptown_personal_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=a0n@y2ei!x@mjo5mkco5=im_($*+8mnlx-e8-yjw3qo$uy2mx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'bootstrap3',
    'groups',
    'posts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ask_uptown_personal_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ask_uptown_personal_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]



LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "test"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "thanks"
```

best,
thanks!

Comment: Tryied to answer you. It would help if you provide urls.py and settings.py code here

Comment: i edited the answer so it has both files ]

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer to static files in my css files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898776/how-to-refer-to-static-files-in-my-css-files)

Comment: check now I added it, it already has the template tag, and didn't work. look at the code now and see.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the path to your static files in the `urls.py` as you can see in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/).

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Also you will need to load static on your template file.

```
{% load static %}
<html>
...
```