# Can't make path right in css on django site

Tags: css, django

I'm working in django, and I have one page that I have inputed css in html file, and from there I need to call background image (to be honest did not work with css in a while). However I make path is not working, even put photo in same folder with html file, created new one, nothing. I would like to put it in `Django_site/static/images/1.jpg`. Currently I'm in Django folder `Django_site/Django_app/templates/Django_app/my.html`.
What do you suggest?

```
.bgimg {
  background-image: url('images/1.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 background-image: url("{% static 'images/1.jpg' %}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can move any CSS that contains static file paths to inline CSS, contained in the template.
```

> [please visit in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898776/how-to-refer-to-static-files-in-my-css-files)