# config driven path for sprites in css

Tags: python, css, django

I use a lot of sprites in my css and all the location to the images has been hardcoded within the css. Now i am planning to move all images to a CDN. Its very hard to change the path in each and every place. Is there a way, to place the location as a variable in config file so that i need not change the path at all places when i move to another CDN. I am using python and django environment.
My sample Code:

```
 #header .topriglogin .telephone{background:url(../images/sprites.gif) -314px -183px no-repeat;}
```

My expectation:

```
#header .topriglogin .telephone{background:url(CONFIG.SPRITE_LOCATION+'sprites.gif') -314px -183px no-repeat;}
```

is it possibele?. please advise

Comment: maybe this link will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589661/generating-dynamic-css

Comment: I cant afford to serve every css via views as it is very costly...

Comment: You can generate it once, for example when something changed in css. And then serve it like static file

Comment: I already tried this but it doesnt seem to be a standard solution as i frequently changes look and feel of the website...but anyway thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) stylesheets which would allow you to use variables, in this case you still need to update the PATH config your own (or write a simple script that does that for you).

```
@SPRITE_LOCATION: '..path/to/sprites/'
#header .topriglogin .telephone{background:url(@SPRITE_LOCATION'sprites.gif') -314px -183px no-repeat;
```